# React Error: Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs

When I check the console React shows the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.
```

I checked my HTML and I have the correct container ID for my React application.

```
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

React loads and the application still runs.

How can I debug this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you have included your scripts (bundle.js or whatever you call it.) twice in your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

By default `create-react-app` sets an id of `root` to the parent `div` where React is injected instead of `app`, that might be the case.

add `document.getElementById('root'));`